# Understanding Zeppelin response time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am  reading a parquet file in my sample and Zepplin says it took 20 sec to read the file in the first snaphot. File size was only 15 mb .
[image]

But when i check the spark webui for duration taken for reading the file as per the below snapshot it says 72 milli sec .
[image]
Why is zeppelin reporting a different timestamp vs spark web ui .

Is zeppelin 20 sec also include spark initialization and shutting down of the cluster.

Comment: You can easily test this by having 3 cells: The first would access something in sqlContext (e.g. just create an empty dataframe). The second cell would do your logic and the third cell would do nothing. Then run it one cell at a time and see the time for the middle cell

Comment: doesnt help much.The behaviour is still same.My main concern is the overhead shown by zeppelin is expected behaviour or not.Which time should i consider to understand the time taken for my logic to complete

Comment: You can do a manual time calculation. Basically define a time function and then call it with the block you are testing. This will tell you how long it took in practice:  def time[R](block: => R): Long = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val totalTime = t1 - t0
    println(s"$totalTime miliseconds")
    totalTime
  }

Comment: but what is the purpose of spark webui in this case then ?what exactly is zeppelin doing in this case for 20 sec

Comment: Check what it gives first. It will tell you where to look next. the "time" function gives you the actual real time the driver waited for a response. If it is the same as zeppelin then the web UI referes to something else and if it is the same as the UI then zeppelin does something else. it is just a way to figure out where to look next